# Aligning td in nested table

Tags: html, nested-table

Hi working to create a newsletter template. At the moment I am stuck as i am unable to change the alignment of the `td`

I have attached a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/zgJvQx), but below is the code! Firstly I don't understand why the elements on the right are aligned left-center? Eitherway I need them to be top-center. Any ideas?

```html
<table align="center" width="690px" bgcolor="#d3e1a3" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="297px" height="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="https://www.naturimgarten.at/assets/images/4/Streicher-ff65c810.jpg" style="max-width:297px;" alt="placeholder" mc:edit="image">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="393px" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>
            name
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            country
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Mind you this is for a newsletter template so think web 1998, most of the fancy web stuff is not usefull here!

Comment: Please check my answer I think that it may solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put `align="center"` in the `td` tag.

```html
<table align="center" width="690px" bgcolor="#d3e1a3" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="297px" height="100%">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" >
            <img src="https://www.naturimgarten.at/assets/images/4/Streicher-ff65c810.jpg" style="max-width:297px;" alt="placeholder" mc:edit="image">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
      <table width="393px" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" >
            name
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" >
            country
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" >text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<table align="center" width="690px" bgcolor="#d3e1a3" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="297px" height="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="https://www.naturimgarten.at/assets/images/4/Streicher-ff65c810.jpg" style="max-width:297px;" alt="placeholder" mc:edit="image">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top; text-align:center">
      <table width="393px" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>
            name
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            country
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```